# RewriteCond 3 or more digit

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have created a 301 redirect but for some reason the 3 digits are being ignored and it uses the 2 digit redirect. it seems like it is reading on the first two digit

```
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.domain.com.com/products [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=31
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.domain.com.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=314
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond`s for a certain `RewriteRule` must be _before_ the `RewriteRule`, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conditions and rewrite rules reversed. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=31$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.domain.com.com/products? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=314$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://www.domain.com.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Also note trailing `?` in rules to strip off existing query string.